# Como enviar mensagens em intervalos de tempo para um lote de emails

Tags: php, mysql, loop, envio-de-email, email

Como posso fazer para que o loop envie de 10 em 10 emails ou a cada X segundos? Quero evitar que os emails caiam na lista de spam.

E como posso fazer para que o código leia um arquivo .txt com os emails listados e futuramente um banco de dados?

```
<?PHP

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

//$email[] = "fulano@email.com.br";

foreach($email as $e){

  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $body = file_get_contents('a.html');

  $mail->AddReplyTo("contato@ereasalvador.com","EREA SSA");
  $mail->SetFrom('contato@ereasalvador.com', 'EREA SSA');

  $mail->AddAddress($e, utf8_decode("$nome[$loop] $sobrenome[$loop]"));
  $mail->Subject = utf8_decode("Sua inscrição foi aceita !");
  $mail->MsgHTML($body);
  //$mail->AddAttachment("edital.pdf"); // Arquivos para anexo

  if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Erro: " . $mail->ErrorInfo . "<br/>";
  } else {
    echo "Mensagem enviada !<br/>";
  }
  $mail->clearAllRecipients();
}

?>
```

Comment: Leitura obrigatória: [PHP mail form doesn't complete sending e-mail](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/1287812)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisa de várias coisas, irei resumir em tópicos:

## Problema 1:

**Alterar o PHP.ini:**

> É preciso alterar para impedir que o PHP encerre o processo por tempo, isso é apenas por segurança, porque por padrão ele será zero, porque será executado a partir da linha de comando!

```
max_execution_time = 0;
```

**Efetuar o loop:**

> Crie um `while` e um `sleep` dentro!

```
while(1  === 1){ // 1 sempre será 1, sempre irá continuar!

// código

sleep(30); // 30 segundos de pausa!
}
```

**Iniciar este loop:**

> É preciso ter acesso ao SSH (ou similar) e executar, por exemplo, o comando `nohup`

```
nohup php /caminho/para/o/arquivo.php &
```

*O nohup tem a função de poder executar em segundo plano, mesmo caso sua conexão com o servidor caia, isso irá fazer com que o script continue ativo mesmo se houver interrupção na comunicação (ou caso desligue o dispositivo, por exemplo).*

## Problema 2:

Carece de dados de como seria a estrutura, por isso estou deduzindo que seria um e-mail por linha, similar ao banco de dados!

```
<?PHP

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$i = 0;
while(1 === 1){ // LOOP

$arquivo = file('arquivo'.$i.'.txt'); 
// Seleciona o arquivo por linha, cada linha uma array. 
// Isso irá selecionar o "arquivo0.txt" ao terminar será "arquivo1.txt", depois "arquivo2.txt", caso queria mante-lo fixo apenas remova o $i.

   $f = 1; // numero de email
foreach($arquivo as $e){

  //nada modificado
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $body = file_get_contents('a.html');

  $mail->AddReplyTo("contato@ereasalvador.com","EREA SSA");
  $mail->SetFrom('contato@ereasalvador.com', 'EREA SSA');

  $mail->AddAddress($e, utf8_decode("$nome[$loop] $sobrenome[$loop]"));
  $mail->Subject = utf8_decode("Sua inscrição foi aceita !");
  $mail->MsgHTML($body);
  //$mail->AddAttachment("edital.pdf"); // Arquivos para anexo

  if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Erro: " . $mail->ErrorInfo . "<br/>";
  } else {
    echo "Mensagem enviada !<br/>";
  }
  $mail->clearAllRecipients();
  //modificado para adicionar sleep

  if($f %10 == 0) { // se for divido por 10 da pausa (10, 20, 30...)!
  sleep(30);
  }
$f++; // acrescenta +1 email
}
sleep(30); // por segurança após o foreach
$i++;
}
?>
```

**Problema logico:**

O que você quer é fazer um loop em algo escasso. Isso é, existe limite de e-mails que podem ser selecionados, portanto o loop "infinito" é irreal e não é importante e nem será útil, uma vez que os arquivos não são infinitos.

Entretanto isso parece não ter isso apontado no texto ou não era esta exata questão, mas é o grande ponto a se considerar. Mas, a solução do "Problema 1" é válida, inclusive para impedir que o PHP encerre o processo antes da conclusão (ou em caso de desconexão do cliente do SSH).

Comment: Inkeliz, vc mais uma vez haha :)

Gostei da primeira solução !

Em relação ao problema 2, eu estarei usando um arquivo de texto onde cada linha terá um email. Ou posso partir para o uso do banco de dados também, para ler as tabelas, algo que ainda tenho que criar

Comment: Neste caso somente faça as alterações no file(), ele "converte" todas as linhas em um item da array. Fiz uma alteração para que envie 10 e-mails e espere X tempo, como tinha dito, não me liguei nisso.

Comment: Por algum motivo, os emails não estão chegando e depois é apresentado um erro:

Internal Server Error

`The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@main-hosting.eu to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.`

No caso, se eu quiser que ele apresente o texto de "Mensagem Enviada" após cada envio, é possível ?

Comment: Isso pode ocorrer por restrição do provedor, principalmente contra spam. Geralmente isso é comum em servidores de ambiente compartilhado (principalmente gratuitos) e VPS. Um outro problema pode ser problema no configuração no .htaccess, também pode causar isso.

Comment: Basta alterar para  `if($mail->Send()) echo "Mensagem enviada";`ao invés de !$mail e depois o else. Se  usar o nohup todo o output será exibido num arquivo chamado `nohup.out` no mesmo lugar onde executou o php.